# Python - Multiply sparse matrix row with non-sparse vector by index

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, numerical-methods

My current software project involves implementing a numeric method for solving linear systems with python (the so called `SOR`-Method).
It basically works like this:

Given a linear system:

```
ax1 + bx2 + cx3 = b1
dx1 + ex2 + fx3 = b2
gx1 + hx2 + ix3 = b3
```

Re-arrange the equations to:

```
x1_new = (b1 - (bx2 + cx3)) / a
x2_new = (b2 - (dx1_new + fx3)) / e
x3_new = (b3 - (gx1_new + hx2_new)) / i
```

As you can see, the `x*_new` values are updating with each line - that's the unfortunate reason why I can't use simple vector-vector prodcuts (I also have to divide by the diagonal element - not multiply it). I have to go element by element.

I would like to work with `sparse`-Matrices. But I didn't find a way yet how to index a sparse matrix and how to perform the operation described above? Like, the only thing I found (regarding this https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html) is to use `A[i].data` which returns the non-zero elements of the row `i`. But there can be a lot of zeros in a row. And also working with a lot of if/else to get the element at the index is not very efficient with a `100.000 x 100.000` matrix.

Any ideas?

Comment: `A[i]` is a new sparse matrix (not a `view`).  `A[i].A` is a dense version of that matrix, with all the zeros restored. (`lil` format does have a version of sparse row views).  Working with elements, rows or columns of sparse matrices is not efficient unless you are willing to get your hands dirty and play with the `data, indices, indptr` attributes directly.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you have any idea, what `A[i, j]` does? Because somehow that is exactly doing what I need.