# Python-Scipy sparse Matrices - what is A[i, j] doing?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

According to my previous question here ([Python - Multiply sparse matrix row with non-sparse vector by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173520/python-multiply-sparse-matrix-row-with-non-sparse-vector-by-index)) direct indexing of sparse matrices is not possible (at least not if you don't want to work with the three arrays by which the `sparse.csr` matrix is defined, `data`, `indices`, `indptr`).
But I just found out, that given a csr-sparse matrix `A`, this operation works fine and produces correct results: `A[i, j]`.
What I also noticed: It is horribly slow, even slower than working with dense matrices.

I couldn't find any information about this indexing method so I am wondering: What exactly is `A[i, j]` doing?

If you like me to take a guess I would say it is producing a dense matrix and then indexing it like you normally would.

Comment: What gave you the idea you can't index a sparse matrix? Doing so is often a bad idea, but it's quite possible.

Comment: @user2357112 Because the typical `A[i][j]` gave me an error. But `A[i,j]` works - do you know what this is doing?

Comment: `A[i][j]` should not be considered the "typical" way to index any NumPy or SciPy data structure. It doesn't even work for regular matrices, let alone sparse matrices.

Comment: Given a 2-dimensional numpy array `A`, `A[i][j]` is indeed possible (at least on my system). Do you mind telling me why `A[i, j]`is so slow?

Comment: As for `A[i, j]`, it gives you the value at row `i` and column `j`, just like regular matrix or array indexing. How it does that varies by SciPy version and sparse matrix format, but it doesn't materialize the whole matrix. That would be an absurdly extravagant waste. You can trace the code path from the relevant `__getitem__` method in the [source code](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/tree/v1.3.0/scipy/sparse), though you'll need to jump around a lot between files due to all the inheritance involved.

Comment: I just noticed that it is alot slower than my implementation with normal, 2D numpy arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [211]: M = sparse.csr_matrix(np.eye(3))                                   
In [212]: M                                                                  
Out[212]: 
<3x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 3 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Indexing with [0] produces a new sparse matrix, (1,3) shape:

```
In [213]: M[0]                                                               
Out[213]: 
<1x3 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 1 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

Trying to index that again gives another sparse matrix, or error.  That's because it is still a 2d object (1,3) shape.

```
In [214]: M[0][1]                                                            
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-214-0661a1f27e52> in <module>
----> 1 M[0][1]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    290             # [i, 1:2]
    291             elif isinstance(col, slice):
--> 292                 return self._get_row_slice(row, col)
    293             # [i, [1, 2]]
    294             elif issequence(col):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py in _get_row_slice(self, i, cslice)
    397 
    398         if i < 0 or i >= M:
--> 399             raise IndexError('index (%d) out of range' % i)
    400 
    401         start, stop, stride = cslice.indices(N)

IndexError: index (1) out of range
```

Indexing with the [0,1] syntax does work, with the two numbers applying to the two different dimensions:

```
In [215]: M[0,1]                                                             
Out[215]: 0.0
```

`A[0][1]` does work with a `np.ndarray`, but that's because the first `[0]` produces an array with 1 less dimension.  But `np.matrix`, and `sparse` returns a 2d matrix, not a 1d one.  It's one reason we don't recommend `np.matrix`.  With `sparse` the matrix nature goes deeper, so we can't simply depricate it.

We can get an idea of the code involved in selecting an element from a sparse matrix by triggering an error:

```
In [216]: M[0,4]                                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-216-4919ae565782> in <module>
----> 1 M[0,4]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    287             # [i, j]
    288             if isintlike(col):
--> 289                 return self._get_single_element(row, col)
    290             # [i, 1:2]
    291             elif isinstance(col, slice):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in _get_single_element(self, row, col)
    868         if not (0 <= row < M) or not (0 <= col < N):
    869             raise IndexError("index out of bounds: 0<=%d<%d, 0<=%d<%d" %
--> 870                              (row, M, col, N))
    871 
    872         major_index, minor_index = self._swap((row, col))

IndexError: index out of bounds: 0<=0<3, 0<=4<3
```

===

Yes, indexing an item in a sparse matrix is slower than indexing in a dense array. It's not because it first converts to dense.  With a dense array indexing an item just requires converting the n-d index to a flat one, and selecting the required bytes in the 1d flat data buffer - and most of that is done in fast compiled code.  But as you can see from the traceback, selecting an item from sparse matrix is more involved, and a lot of it Python.

Sparse `lil` format is designed to be faster for indexing (and especially for setting).  But even that is quite a bit slower than indexing a dense array.  Don't use sparse matrices if you need to iterate, or otherwise repeatedly access individual elements.

===

To give an idea of what's involved with indexing `M`, look at its key attributes:

```
In [224]: M.data,M.indices,M.indptr                                          
Out[224]: 
(array([1., 1., 1.]),
 array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int32),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype=int32))
```

To pick row 0, we have to use `indptr` to select a slice from the others:

```
In [225]: slc = slice(M.indptr[0],M.indptr[1])                               
In [226]: M.data[slc], M.indices[slc]                                        
Out[226]: (array([1.]), array([0], dtype=int32))
```

then to pick col 1, we have to check whether that values is in `indices[slc]`.  If it is, return the corresponding element in `data[slc]`.  If not return 0.

For more complex indexing, sparse actually uses matrix multiplication, having created an `extractor` matrix  from the indices.  It also uses  multiplication to perform row or column sums.

Matrix multiplication is a sparse matrix strength - provided the matrix is sparse enough.  The mathematical roots of sparse formats, especially `csr` are in sparse linear equation problems, such as finite difference and finite element PDES.

===

Here's the underlying attributes for a `lil` matrix

```
In [227]: ml=M.tolil()                                                       
In [228]: ml.data                                                            
Out[228]: array([list([1.0]), list([1.0]), list([1.0])], dtype=object)
In [229]: ml.rows                                                            
Out[229]: array([list([0]), list([1]), list([2])], dtype=object)
In [230]: ml.data[0],ml.rows[0]                                              
Out[230]: ([1.0], [0])          # cf Out[226]
```